# SCSS, how to @extend Nested ampersand "prefix"?

Tags: css, sass

The nested ampersand prefix doesn't get expanded with `@extend`

```
.firstClass{
  color: green;
    &-a{
      color: red;
    }
}
.secondClass{
    @extend .firstClass;
}
```

The expected output would be

```
.firstClass, .secondClass{
    color: green;
}
.firstClass-a, .secondClass-a{
    color: red;
}
```

But the actual output doesn't have the `.secondClass-a` at all.

```
.firstClass, .secondClass{
    color: green;
}
.firstClass-a{
    color: red;
}
```

I found this is an intended behavior to use `@extend` https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2154

But is there a workaround that can extend nested ampersand prefix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the versions I worked on were older but I don't believe it was possible. You could change your properties to a mixin as such:

```
@mixin classStyle {
  color: green;

  &-a{
    color: red;
  }
}

.firstClass {
  @include classStyle;
}

.secondClass {
  @include classStyle;
}
```