# Sass mixin with nested ampersand prefix

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

What's the best way to accomplish the ability to use class prefixes using a mixin with placeholder selectors.

To elaborate, say I have a box class that has 3 sizes but I would like to have the option of having it a different color.

My base classes would be:

```
.box
.box-md
.box-sm
```

If I wanted any of the base class boxes to be green, I would like to be able to specify as such:

```
.box-green
.box-md-green
.box-sm-green
```

How would I be able to do so in as DRY a method as possible?

Similar to this answer but using mixins AND placeholder extends: [SCSS, how to @extend Nested ampersand "prefix"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54521586/scss-how-to-extend-nested-ampersand-prefix)

Here's what I put together so far (which doesn't work)

HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box-green"></div>
<div class="box-sm"></div>
<div class="box-sm-green"></div>
```

CSS (SCSS):

```
// Main style placholder as mixin
@mixin box {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;

  &-green {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

// Placeholders
%box {
  @include box;
}

%small-box {
  @include box;

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}


// Class Definition
.box { @extend %box; }

.box-sm { @extend %small-box; }
```

Pen: https://codepen.io/Aricha_MW/pen/xxKZWbV

Comment: Personally I would forego the complexity in lieu of something like all the major frameworks do and supply utility classes that can be used for other instances in the same purpose as well. Eg; css = `.bg-green {background-color: green}` & html = `<blah class="box bg-green"><blah class="box-sm bg-green">` etc. PS if you're using bootstrap, foundation, whatever, then they're already there and available anyway. That's D.R.Y.

Comment: Although I do agree with you, unfortunately @ChrisW., I don't have this option available as this is for a legacy project with many existing templates which contain tag classes that need to be updated.

Comment: If this is a legacy project, then the only way I think you'll get this to work is to include the nested selector on each of the `box` classes, e.g. `.box { 
  @extend %box;
  &-green {
    background-color: green;
  }
} 

.box-sm { @extend %small-box; &-green {
    background-color: green;
  }}`

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Was just wondering if the above was at all possible. :/
I _could_ use `[class*=" -green"]` but it wouldn't be contained and could potentially be dangerous on a large legacy site.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer but does pose as a solution to the problem:

Our champions are the `@at-root` directive and interpolation here. The solution requires both the use of mixins and placeholder selectors and is a little messy.

If we set up our placeholder selector styles:

```
%box {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
}

%small-box {
    @extend %box;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Then we can let mixins do the rest of the work for us.

First we define our mixin for the variation we want:

```
 @mixin green-bg($selector, $root) {
  // Takes element out of any nesting
  // Then we interpolate our argument variables 
  @at-root{
    #{$root}-green {
      // We can't set a placeholder as an argument so we'll just borrow the string and append the placeholder definer '%'
      @extend %#{$selector};
      background-color: green;
    }
  }
}
```

Then we define our mixins that will help us define our classes

```
@mixin box($parent) {

    @extend %box;

    @include green-bg(box, #{$parent});
}

@mixin small-box($parent) {

    @extend %small-box;

    @include green-bg(small-box, #{$parent});
}
```

When we define our classes they'll look clean like so:

```
.box { @include box(&); }

.box-sm { @include small-box(&); }
```

Here's what the final product looks like in action: https://codepen.io/Aricha_MW/pen/oNvxjEw

Edit: 08/15/2019 - Much cleaner version here: 
https://codepen.io/Aricha_MW/pen/mdbPVXY